# Range projection: equivalent of LINQ select in D?

Tags: linq, d

Is there something like LINQ select in D?

I want to remove from a container all elements contained in the member of objects in a given array. I thought it would be nice if I could do:

```
myContainer.remove( myArray.select!( a => a.member ) ) ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called `map`:

```
import std.algorithm;

myContainer.remove(myArray.map!(a => a.member));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. However I could not compile the following, is it a separate problem?
`import std.container, std.algorithm;
void main() { struct S { string s; }    auto myContainer = redBlackTree!string( "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" );    auto myArray = [ S("aaa" ), S("c") ];    myContainer.remove(myArray.map!(a => a.s));}`

dmd’s output:
test2.d(6): Error: function std.container.RedBlackTree!string.RedBlackTree.remove (Range r) is not callable using argument types (MapResult!(__lambda2, S[]))